# Como envio por ssh un script en mi pagina html?

Tags: python, html5

Tengo una pagina HTML que quiero que uno de los botones envie un script por ssh a un equipo mikrotik, mis preguntas son las siguentes que lenguaje utilizo, en caso que sea python como agrego ese código a ese botón que ya yo creé o si tengo que rescribir mi código desde el principio.

Disculpenme por mi falta de corcordancia tengo un script en python que envia un codigo por ssh a mi mikrotik el cual le da release a la interfas correspondiente del siguiente script. Tengo una pagina en HTML con 3 botones el cual quiero que uno haga esa funcion del ssh pero no encuentro manera.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('xxxxx', username='xxxx', password='xxxxxxxxxx')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('/ip dhcp-client release [find interface=wlan5]')


print("Cuenta Cerrada")
```

Comment: favor de leer [ask] pues tu pregunta esta mal planteada, debes ser claro no solo en lo que quieres hacer, sino además que has intentado? que te ha fallado; pues al solicitar en que lenguaje? se basa en opiniones y eso será motivo de cierre

Comment: La secuencia sería mas o menos así: HTML (cliente navegador) -> petición a servidor (click en boton de form get/post o ajax via javascript) -> servidor valida petición ( mediante script en lenguaje de servidor, podes usar python ) -> script pide al servidor que se comunique con el microtik via ssh ( mediante un exec local o con una librería ) -> script retorna resultado al cliente ( un nuevo HTML o un mensaje si usaste ajax ). Un ejemplo de SSH con python+librería tenes en https://stackoverflow.com/a/50967052/1423096